# calculate text file numeric data through arrays c++

Tags: c++

I have a file that looks like this:

```
89369865 19 20 17 14 10  5 16 20 20 12  7 49  82  7
55959810 36 18 18 19 20 17 20 17  7 15  9 75  81 10
56569325 20  7 14 12 20 18 18  9 17 12  5 61  98  9
92457613 35  6 15 19 20 20 13 18 17  8 11 40  57 10
81596872 25 20 11 14 18 19 16 12 13 10 12 68  86  9
79916777 39 20 20  8 18 19 11 14 13 18 17 61  97  7
01234567 29 15 15 20 10 10  4 16 16 12 10 71  48 10
81383418 38 10 12 18 17 17 16 16 19 19  4 72  92  3
```

just with 50 students total.

I have opened the file already through code
1. how do I calculate each row separate?
2. how do I create a loop that will calculate each row separately and give total for each row?

thanks!

Comment: Could you please be more specific and also comment your file in code form please

Comment: Don't be a "Code Grinch" - show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I suggest using a structure and searching the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file struct"

Comment: What is the purpose or name of the first column?

Comment: Are the number of elements after the "student id" (I presume) always 12?

Comment: im not trying to get all the answers from you guys i just don't know how to start it! the first column is student id , the next number is lab points and the newt 10 numbers are 10 assignments , i just don't know how to separate them and calculate per line , per student , per category . thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since there is one record per line, `std::getline` will be your friend, as will `std::string`.

Let's try something:

```
std::string record_text;
std::getline(my_data_file, record_text);
```

We can use `std::istringstream` to help convert the text record into numbers:

```
std::istringstream record_stream(record_text);
std::vector<int> student_values;
int student_id;
record_stream >> student_id;
int value;
while (record_stream >> value)
{
  student_values.push_back(value);
}
```

I'm using a `std::vector` to contain the student values; you may be required to use another container.

**Edit 1: Overloading extraction operators**
If you want to impress your instructor and fellow students, you should model the records with a `struct` and overload the input operators:

```
struct Student_Record
{
  int id;
  std::vector<int> values;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(istream& input, Student_Record& sr);
};
std::istream& operator>>(istream& input, Student_Record& sr)
{
  // See above on how to read a line of data.
  // Be sure to use "sr." when accessing the structure variables,
  //    such as sr.id
  return input;
}
```

The overloaded operator allows you to have simpler input:

```
std::vector<Student_Record> database;
Student_Record sr;
while (my_data_file >> sr)
{
  database.push_back(sr);
}
```

Be sure to recommend StackOverflow to your instructor and fellow students.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: Because today is Friday on the Pacific Coast and I thought I would be nice and present a foundation.  Sometimes, a nudge can help.  I didn't provide the entire program.  Only some advance techniques.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Nicely done sir +1

Comment: Or should I be more honest and say I answered it for the reputation points. :-)

Comment: its says" friend used outside of class" error , what does it mean ?                     it is hard to start , do i midstream the file first and open it?

Comment: I added "using std::istream;" before the struct and it compiles with no errors using g++.